# Shuffling divs using C# behindcode

Tags: c#, asp.net, random, code-behind

I have an aspx page that has 10 divs. 6 of those divs need to be positioned at random every time the page refreshes. Those divs have a lot of content in them so I have to avoid doing this with javascript. I was told this could be achieved using the codebehind, which is in c#.
Here is an idea:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var plantripsmall = new List<HtmlGenericControl> {
        div1, div2
    };

    DrawShuffled(plantripsmall);
}

public void DrawShuffled(List<HtmlGenericControl> orig)
{

    Random rnd = new Random();

    var shuffled = orig.OrderBy(s => rnd.Next()).ToList();

    int i = 0;
    while (i < orig.ToArray().Length)
    {
        orig[i].InnerHtml = shuffled[i].InnerHtml;
        i++;
    }
}
```

but that is not really working.

```
Cannot get inner content of div2 because the contents are not literal
```

and besides i would like to avoid controls

UPDATE
The issue seems to be my include file inside that second div:

```
<div runat="server" id="div2">
<!--#include virtual="files/hello.aspx" -->
...more content
</div>
```

do you know how I would get past this issue?

Comment: Can you try moving the call to PreRender event?

Comment: i tried that. same error. I am starting to think this is not the right approach though.

Comment: Does this happen on a postback?

Comment: it's a not a postback page

Answer (score 2):

You should really be using jQuery or some other client-side javascript to do this. I don't understand why you have a requirement that javascript won't work for this.

Comment: because it wont be as fast as drawing server side and there are a ton of other js bindings that might get wonky

Comment: I disagree. I think the correct approach to this problem would be to use jquery to select the divs you want into a list and randomly re-order them on the page body. The other js bindings shouldn't have any problem with this. Name your divs appropriately and select them carefully and you won't have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why I don't get that error. just tried this and it works.

```
       HtmlGenericControl div1 = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
       HtmlGenericControl div2 = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
       div1.InnerHtml = "test1";
       div2.InnerHtml = "test2";
       var lst = new List<HtmlGenericControl>
       {
          div1,
          div2
       };
       Random rnd = new Random();

       var shuffled = lst.OrderBy(s => rnd.Next()).ToList();

        int i = 0;
        while (i < lst.ToArray().Length)
        {
            lst[i].InnerHtml = shuffled[i].InnerHtml;
            i++;
        }

        this.Controls.Add(div1);
        this.Controls.Add(div2);
```

Comment: ah! the issue seems to be my include file inside that second div:
<div runat="server" id="div2">
                <!--#include virtual="files/hello.aspx" -->
...more content
</div>

do you know how I would get past this issue?